# rephrasement of sql queries

Tags: php, sql

I need to extract all members whose bday fall within a given date range.. irrespective of Year.. tat means, when i need from Jan 1 to Jan 30, it should pull all those members who have bday in Jan.. 
i found this query handy..

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM family_member WHERE DATE_FORMAT(wedding_date, '%c-%d') BETWEEN 
DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d')  AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d') order by MONTH(wedding_date), DAYOFMONTH(wedding_date)";
```

this query works well if the from month is less than to month.. that means will yield the desired results if the query is to pull from jan to feb. But gives NO records if i need from Dec 1 to Jan 30 (i need data from Dec 1 to Dec 31 and Jan 1 to Jan 31) irrespective of its Year...

i have a workaround wherein

1. i need to split this into two queries
2. execute each of these queries
3. and club the result and then echo

but wish to know if this is the only possible way or if i can replace it one single SQL query...

Comment: You've got a real brain-tickler here. This may be one of those instances where it could potentially save A LOT of time and headache if you could implement a few UX design regulations such as using checkboxes to ask which full months does a user want to search for and parse it out into an OR based WHERE clause with a statement for each month selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this easily enough using AND and OR in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM family_member 
WHERE 
  (DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d') < DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d') 
   AND 
    DATE_FORMAT(wedding_date, '%c-%d') BETWEEN 
    DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d') 
   )
   OR
   (DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d') > DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d')
    AND
    DATE_FORMAT(wedding_date, '%c-%d') BETWEEN 
    DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d')
   )
ORDER BY MONTH(wedding_date), DAYOFMONTH(wedding_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM family_member
    WHERE
     (
     DATE_FORMAT(wedding_date, '%c-%d')
     BETWEEN
     DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%c-%d')
     AND   
     DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%Y')=DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%Y')
     )
    OR
     (
     DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%Y')<DATE_FORMAT('2014-".$to_month."-".$to_day."', '%Y')
     And
      (
      DATE_FORMAT(wedding_date, '%c-%d')
      BETWEEN
      DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-12-31', '%c-%d')
      )
     OR
      (
      DATE_FORMAT(wedding_date, '%c-%d')
      BETWEEN
      DATE_FORMAT('2014-1-1', '%c-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-".$from_month."-".$from_day."', '%c-%d')
      AND
      DATE_FORMAT('2013-12-31', '%c-%d')
      )
     ) order by MONTH(wedding_date), DAYOFMONTH(wedding_date)";
```